# Script en Google Sheets para realizar acciones en DRIVE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

¿Es posible con un script en un Gsheet crear una carpeta con nombre determinado y crear dentro de ella un conjunto de copias de archivos?

Estas listas de archivos estarían listados con sus ID en la Gsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Usa [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) y el método [createFoler(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfoldername) para crear una carpeta y luego [makeCopy(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(Folder)), ambos son del [servicio Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/).